# wxpython combobox value parameter not setting initial value properly

Tags: python, wxpython, python-3.7

I'm writing a script with the code below, and it isn't working because setting the `value` parameter should set an initial value on the combobox, as the code and pictures state. Does anybody have a solution for this?

```py
self.algorithms = {...}
self.algorithm = wx.ComboBox(self.pnl, value='--Select--', choices=list(self.algorithms.keys()),
                                     style=wx.CB_READONLY)
self.algorithm.SetPosition((50, 80))
```

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That should work if the `keys` in the dictionary are strings.

If not you should be getting an error from:

```
choices=list(self.algorithms.keys())
```

`choices` should be a `list` of `strings`

In that case try:

```
choices=[str(k) for k in self.algorithms]
```

instead.

**Edit** For style `wx.CB_READONLY`

> the string must be in the combobox choices list

This is not the case for other styles

So care must be taken if using the index for that selection

Here is some simple code that should work:

```
import wx

class Myframe(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        self.my_choices = {"Choose a sport":0,"Board Sports":1,"Ball Sports":2,"Fight Sports":3}
        #self.my_choices = ["Board Sports","Ball Sports","Fight Sports"]
        self.my_subchoices = [[],["Skate boarding","Surfing","Ski boarding"],["Football","Cricket","Rugby"],["Boxing","Wrestling","Karate"]]
        pan = wx.Panel(self)
        self.cbx = wx.ComboBox(pan, -1, value = "Choose a sport", pos=(10,30), size=(300,30),choices=list(self.my_choices),style=wx.CB_DROPDOWN | wx.CB_READONLY )
        self.cbx.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.on_selection)

    def on_selection(self, evt):
        Choice = self.cbx.GetSelection()
        msg = ""
        #
        # Ignore choice 0 because of style wx.CB_READONLY or include a blank entry
        # for choice 0 in my_subchoices
        for x in self.my_subchoices[Choice]:
            msg += x+"\n"
        self.cbx.SetToolTip(msg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = wx.App()
    Myframe().Show()
    App.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi... I've made sure all of the keys are strings, @Legorooj is right there. I'll look at your code and see if it gives me any pointers - Thanks!

Comment: Aha! Figured out why it isn't working - `wx.CB_READONLY` is one of my styles, and that's preventing it from working properly. Do you know how to fix this? https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.ComboBox.html#wx.ComboBox.SetValue

Comment: Thx - I was hoping there was another way, but I'll just have to add a validator one the button selection.